Geometry question involving a sparsely-related tangent condition

Triangle ABC is acute-angled with circumcircle $\Gamma$ and orthocenter H so that $AB \neq AC$. Let AH met BC and $\Gamma$ at D and E, respectively. Let F be the midpoint of BC. The line tangent to the circumcircle of triangle DEF at D meets the lines AB and AC at M and L, respectively. Prove that $MD = DL$.


Here, I've included G as ray $HF \cap \Gamma$ and $HF=FG$.
The problem is that there is this tangent condition that I can't seem to usefully incorporate in any way I choose. The most useful piece of information I got was $HG \perp ML$.
($\angle ODF = \angle OFD = \angle DFH \Rightarrow HF \parallel OD \Rightarrow HG \perp ML$)
I've tried the following:

Angle chasing using the perpendicular tangent condition. This seemed to not work, even with reverse reconstruction.

Power of a point seemed rather likely with the tangent condition, but both L and M are infeasable.

I tried Menalaus' Theorem along with Ceva's Theorem, as well as turning them into areas. This didn't work.

Similar triangles by using lengths. It doesn't seem there are any good similar triangles.

Reflecting. I made parallelograms, and made the orthocentre of ACE. However, there was still a bottleneck, even with reverse reconstruction.


Dilation or projective geometry doesn't seem likely to be usable for this question. I'd rather not use computational methods (e.g. barycentric, coordinates, complex bashing) to solve the problem, although I am tolerant to minor usages of trigonometry.
Here's a few things that I've noticed that might help:

Potential butterfly theorem. However, there is a clear lack of cyclic quadrilaterals, regardless of dilation or not.

Inclusion of D, E and H could suggest using their well known midpoint properties (maybe adding another midpoint of triangle ABC?)

Some crazy application of Pascal's Theorem.

More analysis on the properties and identity of the point M.



Added to question.

Changed. Thank you!

One trig bash approach is to calculate what $\angle LDC$ has to be in order for $ML$ to be the median [ $\tan^{-1} ( \tan \beta - \tan \gamma) $ ], and then show that $\angle DEF$ is equal to that. The benefit of this is that it removes all of the "awkward constructions", and is pure side length chasing.

Another method.
Firstly, let's draw a perpendicular line from point $M$ to the line $BC$, intersecting at $P$.

Considering the inscribed angle theorem, we have:
$$
\angle 1 = \angle 2 \quad\quad 
\angle 7 = \angle 8 \quad \quad 
$$
Considering $MP\bot PC$ and $AE\bot PC$, we have:
$$
\angle 6 = \angle 7
$$
Considering $AE\bot PC$ and $OD\bot ML$, we have:
$$
\angle 3 = \angle 4
$$
Considering the circle $O$ is the circumcircle of triangle $DEF$, we have:
$$
\angle 4 = \angle 5
$$
Using all the derived equal angles, we can obtain the following similar triangles:

i.e.
$$
\Delta PBM \sim \Delta DBA \sim \Delta DEC
$$
$$
\Delta ALD \sim \Delta BEF
$$
$$
\Delta PDM \sim \Delta DEF
$$
Now, we let  (using the similar triangles in the first subfigure)
$$
PB = a \quad\quad BD = b \quad\quad DE = c 
$$
$$
PM = ka \quad\quad AD = kb \quad\quad DC = kc
$$

Using the similar triangles in the thrid subfigure, we have:
$$
\frac{a+b}{c} = \frac{MD}{EF} = \frac{ka}{\frac{kc-b}{2}}
$$
Eliminate the $a$, ( i.e. using the equality, we can derive $a = \frac{b(kc-b)}{kc+b}$  ), we have:
$$
\frac{MD}{EF} = \frac{kb}{\frac{kc+b}{2}}
$$
Now, using the similar triangles in the second subfigure, we have:
$$
 \frac{DL}{EF} = \frac{AD}{BF} = \frac{kb}{\frac{kc+b}{2}}
$$
Obviously, we finally get our target equality relation:
$$
\frac{MD}{EF} = \frac{DL}{EF}  \quad\Longrightarrow\quad MD = DL
$$

You can use harmonic pencils: I'll refer to the following diagram.

Let $D'$ on $BC$ be such that $BDCD'$ is a harmonic range --- here constructed using complete quadrilateral $AH_CHH_B$. By the harmonic pencil $A(D'CDB)$ if we show that the lines $AD'$ and $ML$ are parallel we win.
Let $G'$ (suggestively named) be the intersection of $AD'$ and $\Gamma$. By power of the point $D'$ with $\Gamma$ and the two blue circles, $G'$ lies on $\omega = (AH_CHH_B)$ so $HG \perp AD'$. By your observation, it will suffice to show that $FHG'$ are collinear. One proof of this is given in this answer, I'll give one to my taste.
We will first show that $AG'DF$ are concylic. Unpacking the definition of a harmonic range, we see that $DD'\cdot DF = D'C\cdot D'B$, so the assertion follows from the power of $D'$ as before.
Edit: this is enough to conclude. By inscribed angle, $\angle FG'A = \angle FDA = \pi = \angle HG'A$, so $FHG'$ are collinear.
Old proof, for posterity:
Finally, set $K$ to be the intersection of $D'H$ and $\omega$. There is an inversion which sends $\omega$ to line $BC$, therefore $G'\leftrightarrow D'$ and $H\leftrightarrow D$. Therefore $D'HK$ is mapped to $(AG'DF)$, so $K\leftrightarrow F$ and in particular $AKF$ are collinear. Since $HK \perp AK$, $H$ is the orthocentre of $AFD'$ so (at last) $FH \perp AD'$.
The end of this seems to make $G'$ irrelevant, but I can't immediately see how to simplify the argument. (See above addition.)
